# How to setup a service like Rapidshare, Megaupload for company intranet?

Tags: file-sharing

I would like to start a service like Megaupload, Rapidshare to allow my NON technical colleague to upload files then receive a link to share with customers or suppliers.

Yes, you can tell me "Exist yousendit, megaupload etc." but I would like to create something internally to our server!

Do you know if exists some software, php or asp.net or anyelse that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZendTo is one option

http://zend.to/

*The safe, secure and completely free way to transfer large files around the Web.
ZendTo is a completely free web-based system, which you can run on your own server with complete safety and security. It runs from any Linux or Unix server or virtualisation system and there is no size limit and it will send files one and a half times faster than by email.*